# Работа формы в php

Tags: php

```
echo "<input type=\"radio\"
name=\"question\" value=\"first\"
checked> 1 вариант <input
type=\"radio\" name=\"question\" value=\"second\"> 2 Вариант";
```

Я так понял, данная форма при выборе одного из вариантов должна отправить, что переменная question присваивает значение second или first. Это верно?

Answer (score 2):

Да радиокнопки с одинаковым name образуют группу кнопок и этому имени присваивается value выбранной кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

так и есть проверить достаточно просто:

```
<?
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method="POST" action="/index.php">
<input type="radio" name="question" value="first" checked> 1 вариант 
<input type="radio" name="question" value="second"> 2 Вариант
<input type="submit" value="проверить">
</form>
```